# Django - Select field not showing Options

Tags: python, html, django, forms, select

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
class CharApp(forms.Form):
    VAMPIRE = 'VP'
    DRAUGR = 'DR'
    BAELNORN = 'BN'
    LICH = 'LH'
    SHADOW = 'SW'
    RACE_CHOICES = (
        ('VP', 'Vampire'),
        ('DR', 'Draugr'),
        ('BN', 'Baelnorn'),
        ('LH', 'Lich'),
        ('SW', 'Shadow'),
    )
    app_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    char_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Character Name')
    race = forms.Form(forms.ChoiceField( choices = RACE_CHOICES))
    date_applied = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Date Applied')
    background = models.TextField(verbose_name='Background')
    account_id = models.IntegerField(default=1, verbose_name='Account ID')
    submitted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

create.html

```
    <p><label for="race">Race:</label>
        <select name="{{ form.race.choices }}">
            {% for choices in form.race.choices %}
                {{ form.race.choices }}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

For some reason the select section of the html doesn't loop at all and shows no value at all or the text.

Comment: Is there a reason why you specify the choices yourself?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand why i specify the choices myself. Its so that the form can read and select from only those choices?  - I'm not sure if im undertanding it correctly.

Comment: You are confusing a lot of things here. A form uses fields from the `django.forms.fields` module and not model fields from `django.db.models`. Second you do not need to wrap a field into a `Form` instance. Where did you take that information from?

Comment: I was googling the same error i had and saw similar results. And was trying them out.

Comment: Also for the initial part of this i was following on how to do a web document via https://github.com/evennia/evennia/wiki/Web-Character-Generation this page. But it didn't include information about select fields and it was all in one line for the text. So i had to reformat the HTML page. Im trying to make it look nicer and get the page done first.

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont use builtin django Select?

```
from django import forms
>>> CHOICES = (('1', 'First',), ('2', 'Second',))
>>> choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES)
>>> choice_field.choices
[('1', 'First'), ('2', 'Second')]
>>> choice_field.widget.choices
[('1', 'First'), ('2', 'Second')]
>>> choice_field.widget.choices = ()
>>> choice_field.choices = (('1', 'First and only',),)
>>> choice_field.widget.choices
[('1', 'First and only')]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#widgets-inheriting-from-the-select-widget

**EDIT:** As im looking at your code you doing something pretty weird... you can defing your Form in your models and you settings the models fields in your form? i guess you missplacing the concepts

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models

# THIS IS YOUR MODEL, WILL BE PERSISTED IN YOUR DATABASE
class Race(models.Model):
    ... # Here you will place fields related to the race, as name, date and etc...


class CharApp(models.Model):
    VAMPIRE = 'VP'
    DRAUGR = 'DR'
    BAELNORN = 'BN'
    LICH = 'LH'
    SHADOW = 'SW'
    RACE_CHOICES = (
        ('VP', 'Vampire'),
        ('DR', 'Draugr'),
        ('BN', 'Baelnorn'),
        ('LH', 'Lich'),
        ('SW', 'Shadow'),
    )

    app_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    char_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Character Name')
    race = models.ForenignKey(Race, related_name="charapp_race")
    date_applied = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Date Applied')
    background = models.TextField(verbose_name='Background')
    account_id = models.IntegerField(default=1, verbose_name='Account ID')
    submitted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

*forms.py* #create this file at your app folder

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.models import Article

from .models import CharApp, RACE_CHOICES

# this is your form
class CharAppForm(ModelForm):
    # Here you can change the widget or add new fields that is not related your model form
    race = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES) #if you want to change the default form widget to this field

    class Meta:
        model = CharApp
        fields = ['__all__'] # This will get all fields from your form, or just place each field you want to display
```

Keep in mind to create your form instance at your view.py

```
from .models import CharApp
from .forms import CharAppForm

# The function that will render your html or give you responses from your backend to your frontend

def your_view(request): 
    form = ConfigAppForm() # This will render your form with no value (so when pages render)
    if request.method == "POST:
        form = ConfigAppForm(request.POST) # This will bring the data that user have filled at your html and sended to your backend
        if form.is_valid(): # Check if the form is valid and able to save
            form.save() # will save the instance of your ConfigApp at your database
```

In your html you can call

```
<!-- This will render your entire form -->
{{ form.as_p}}
<!-- Obs: If you need to add css class or something like it you can override the widget at your form.py and add this classes thought attr of your field -->
```

Some following guides to understand the concept of MVC (or MTV of django)

MVC: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/what-is-mvc-really

MTV Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/faq/general/

Django Views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/

Django Models: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/

Django Models Forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/

**EDIT**

If you want to make your code works without doing anything i said before just do that

```
VAMPIRE = 'VP'
DRAUGR = 'DR'
BAELNORN = 'BN'
LICH = 'LH'
SHADOW = 'SW'
RACE_CHOICES = (
    ('VP', 'Vampire'),
    ('DR', 'Draugr'),
    ('BN', 'Baelnorn'),
    ('LH', 'Lich'),
    ('SW', 'Shadow'),

class CharApp(forms.Form):
    ...
    race = forms.Form(forms.ChoiceField( choices = RACE_CHOICES))
```

Comment: I'm trying to keep the code compact as possible. This seems like an overcomplication of what i need.

Comment: If you need code be compact you should use flask instead of django

Comment: I mean i was trying to follow this tutorial https://github.com/evennia/evennia/wiki/Web-Character-Generation - to get a web character generation page. But it doesn't explain on how to do the select/lists.

Comment: And of course - I wanted to design it as HTML (Hence why i changed to the other format) so i could have it looking nice.

Comment: Yet this code is following the Django guides and yours dont

Comment: you can use ´form.as_p´ to get one RAW form, or you can use ´{{ form.race }}´  to get just the input (<input type...) and with attr like i said you add classes to this input, or you can even get just the data from your form and in clean method you add it to each field and run the valid form

Comment: just to knowledge, Django users and the framework by itself expect that you follow the style guide, while flask framework is better to do things compact, like everything in one file

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what flask is - I mean im still learning all this as i go. And the guide and software seems to use Django. So not sure how it would work with flask.

Comment: Just keep with django then, but dont try to make to much compact as you go, just follow the tutorial

Comment: I know, but like i said the tutorial had no explaination on how to do a select form for it. Only text.

Comment: I think im gonna start over again with the Web character tutorial, following and reading it a bit more closely to see if i can understand it better. Or i could have a look at Flask and see if i can use that instead. Wish there were easier ways to learn how to do this.

Comment: i placed one second edit to makeyour CHOICES work, check this out if you want to keep your code as it is

Answer (score 0):

you must declear race field in form as CharField not Form. look this

```
race = forms.ChoiceField(choices = RACE_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select())
```

then in your template print options like this

```
{% for key, value in form.race.choices %}
    <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```